# Proving that a map is a weak homotopy equivalence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Consider the category of pointed topological spaces $C$. Suppose objects $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h \in C$. Suppose we also have the commuting diagrams where all the morphisms are serre fibrations $$\begin{array}& &a&\to &b\\
&\downarrow & &\downarrow \\
&c &\to &d\end{array}$$
$$\begin{array}& &e&\to &f\\
&\downarrow & &\downarrow \\
&g &\to &h\end{array}$$
and maps $f_{ae}:a \to e,f_{bf}:b \to f, f_{cg}:c \to g,f_{dh}:d \to h$ satisfying the obvious commutativity conditions. Then I want to show that if any three of the maps $f_{ae},f_{bf}, f_{cg},f_{dh}$ are weak homotopy equivalence then so is the other one. If anyone has any hints or suggestions it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I meant any three of  $f_{ae},f_{bf}, f_{cg},f_{dh}$ are weak homotopy equivalences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this true? If we take $a = b = \ldots = S^1$, and $f: S^1 \to S^1; z \mapsto z^2$, then we have

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
S^1 @>id>> S^1 \\
@VidVV @VVidV \\
S^1 @>>id> S^1
\end{CD}$$

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
S^1 @>id>> S^1 \\
@VidVV @VVfV \\
S^1 @>>f> S^1
\end{CD}$$

both commuting, and all maps being Serre fibrations ($f: S^1 \to S^1$ is a covering map of degree 2).

But we can then take $f_{ae}, f_{bf}, f_{cg} = id$, and $f_{dh} = f$ (i.e. all the maps between the diagrams are the identity except in the bottom-right corner) then we get a commutative cube, with three of the maps between diagrams being the identity, and the fourth not a weak homotopy equivalence.

Comment: Your counter example seems right Thanks a lot