# Proving weak homotopy equivalence of a map

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

This is a modification of the question I previously asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829538/proving-that-a-map-is-a-weak-homotopy-equivalence).

Consider the category of pointed topological spaces $C$. Suppose objects $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h \in C$. Suppose we also have the commuting diagrams where all the morphisms are serre fibrations $$\begin{array}& &a&\to &b\\
&\downarrow & &\downarrow \\
&c &\to &d\end{array}$$
$$\begin{array}& &e&\to &f\\
&\downarrow & &\downarrow \\
&g &\to &h\end{array}$$
and maps $f_{ae}:a \to e,f_{bf}:b \to f, f_{cg}:c \to g,f_{dh}:d \to h$ satisfying the obvious commutativity conditions. Then I want to show that if  $f_{bf}, f_{cg},f_{dh}$ are weak homotopy equivalence then so is $f_{ae}$.

My Try: I tried to use the fact that serre fibrations give rise to long exact sequence of homotopy groups and somehow get to a configuration in which I can use five lemma. But I could not get it this way. If anyone has any hints or suggestions it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: am i right that the condition "all the morphisms are serre fibrations" is not necessary, because (up to homotopy equivalence) any map is a Serre fibration?

Comment: @AndreyRyabichev I believe this condition is actually necessary because otherwise I have a counter example.

Comment: maybe, when you change your $a,b,c,d$ [in the following way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_fiber), your example will work?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*for make an example, i just reverse the arrows in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1829547/257176):*

If we take $a = b = \ldots = S^1$, and $f: S^1 \to S^1; z \mapsto z^2$, then we have

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
S^1 @>f>> S^1 \\
@VfVV @VVidV \\
S^1 @>>id> S^1
\end{CD}$$

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
S^1 @>id>> S^1 \\
@VidVV @VVidV \\
S^1 @>>id> S^1
\end{CD}$$

both commuting, and all maps being Serre fibrations ($f: S^1 \to S^1$ is a covering map of degree 2).

But we can then take $f_{bf}, f_{cg}, f_{dh} = id$, and $f_{ae} = f$ (i.e. all the maps between the diagrams are the identity except in the top-left corner) then we get a commutative cube, with three of the maps between diagrams being the identity, and the fourth not a weak homotopy equivalence.

Comment: thanks a lot I should have thought of this.